# what is a bare-bones Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml to run python scripts (with specific versions of python/packages)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

My laptop (Macbook) pre-installed an old version of Python (2.7).

I have a couple of different python scripts `task1.py` and `task2.py` that require Python 3.7 and `pip install some_handy_python_package`

Several online sources say updating the system-wide version of Python on a Macbook could break some (unspecified) legacy apps.

Seems like a perfect use-case for Docker, to run some local scripts with a custom Python setup, but I do not find any online examples for this simple use case:

- Laptop hosts folder `mystuff` has two scripts `task1.py` and `task2.py` (plus a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file)
- Create a docker image with python 3.7 and whatever required packages, eg `pip install some_handy_python_package`
- Can run any local-hosted python scripts from inside the docker container

  - perhaps something like `docker run -it --rm some-container-name` THEN at a bash prompt 'inside' docker run the script(s) via `python task1.py`
  - or perhaps something like `docker-compose run --rm console python task1.py`

I assume the Dockerfile starts off something like this:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install some_handy_python_package
```

but I'm not sure what to add to either the Dockerfile or a docker-compose.yml file so I can **either** a) run in Docker a bash prompt that lets me run `python task1.py`, or b) lets me define a 'console' service that can invoke `python task1.py` from the command line

Comment: Take a look at Conda https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html. With this you can create arbitrary environments with completely different Python versions (or no Python at all)

Comment: if I was doing a lot of python development Conda does look like an awesome tool, thanks. But we already Dockerize all our Rails dev't so I'm committed to finding how to do something similar for system-independent Python scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps someone else, here's a kind of basic example how to run some local-folder python scripts inside Dockerized python environment. (A better example would setup a volume share within the Dockerfile.)

```
cd sc2
pwd      # /Users/thisisme/sc2`  -- you use this path later, when run docker, to set a volume share
```

Create Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install some_package
```

Build the container, named `rp` in this example:

`docker build -t rp .`

In the local folder, create some python scripts, for example: task1.py

```
# task1.py
from some_package import SomePackage
# do some stuff
```

In the local folder, run the script in the container by creating a `app` share point:

`docker run --rm -v YOUR_PATH_TO_FOLDER:/app rp python /app/task1.py`

Specifically:

`docker run --rm -v /Users/thisisme/sc2:/app rp python /app/task1.py`

And sometimes it is handy to run the python interpreter in the container while developing code:

`docker run -it --rm rp1`

```
>>> 2 + 2
4
>>>
```